# Ловим запросы с компьютера

Tags: c#, запрос

Как словить, когда компьютер шлет `POST`-запросы куда-угодно? Я понимаю, что надо что-то вроде такого:

```
while(true) {
    if(идет запрос) {
        var post = postvalue;
    }
}
```

Но вот с матчастью проблемы. Может кто-то видел, какие классы нужно покурить?

Comment: А может сниффером. Например wireshark (под windows не видит loopback, т.е. POST только наружу)

Comment: я сам хочу такую программу написать :) мне готовое ни к чему

Comment: Кстати, [первая же ссылка](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C) по запросу [C# sniffer](https://www.google.ru/search?q=C%23+sniffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут уже идет функционал, поддерживающийся WinAPI. "Ловля" мессэджов от системы( из очереди, потому что PostMessage именно кидает новое сообщение в очередь системных сообщений ). Без прямого импорта этого, к сожалению, не сделать - весь функционал WinAPi скрыт за кулисами .NET. Вот, как, например, импортировать функцию WinAPI ShellExecute:

```
...
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        public static extern int ShellExecuteA(int hwnd,
                                               string lpOperation,
                                               string lpFile,
                                               string lpParameters,
                                               string lpDirectory,
                                               int nShowCmd);
...
```

Вызов:

```
ShellExecuteA(0, "open", lpFile, "", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 7);
```

Думаю, как импортировать Winapi`шную GetMesage, допрете сами...а вопрос хороший, кстати!

Comment: пасиб, попробую, просто у меня был открыт фаербаг и я зашел в ВК и увидел как передалось логин и пароль...это меня возмутило, их же можно просто перехватить и выслать злоумышленнику...

Comment: Напомню, что многие определения и структуры WinAPI для .NET можно найти на [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/)

Comment: а разве GetMesage поймает post? он вроде вообще с http не работает

Answer (score 0):

Формграббер из .Net не получится =)

Comment: я это уже понял :) попробую на си написать, чуть-чуть знания есть по этому языку

Comment: Чуть-чуть в C++ - это хотя бы среднее знание STL =)